# How do I resolve this CORS error during Azure AD SSO post logout sequence?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have a webforms web app in which I'm integrating Azure AD SSO. I have a login sequence working ok, but the post-logout redirect is giving me a CORS error.

In my call to `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()` in my startup class I've got the following (actually the the URI is not hard-coded but set up in the web.config)

```
.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44370/LoggedOut.aspx"
```

The error is

> SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'https://localhost:44370' did not find
>   'https://localhost:44370' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response
>   header for cross-origin  resource at
>   'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44370%2FLoggedOut.aspx&x-client-SKU=ID_NET451&x-client-ver=5.2.1.0'.

I have tried calling  `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", {"*"})` but no change.

edit: I have the URL configured in the RedirectURIs section for the app in Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have the URL configured in the RedirectURIs section for the app in the Azure portal but it should be configured under Properties in App Registrations > My App > Properties > Logout URL

The Reply URL section should just have whatever page you want the user to get redirected to after logging in.

[image: Logout URL]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkG1g.png)

Comment: I assume you are only working locally and do not have a published app?